# Changing Str to Float Loses Digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program where I get numbers like: 0.18869952857494354248046875

I need to change these from string to float, but when I do that, I get: 0.18869952857494354

Why does python cut off ~10 digits and how can I retain them in the transfer?

Comment: Cause floating point math: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Use a library like the built-in decimal library, or the 3rd party mpmath library. Normal floats don't have the precision you need.

Answer (score 3):

The limitations of floating point math mean that you can't have arbitrarily long floating point numbers: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

You can get around this by using the `decimal` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal("0.18869952857494354248046875")
>>> a
Decimal('0.18869952857494354248046875')
>>> b = Decimal("0.111111111111111111111111")
>>> a + b
Decimal('0.29981063968605465359157975')
>>> a * b
Decimal('0.02096661428610483805338539570')
```

By default the `decimal` library has 28 places of precision but you can change this using `getcontext().prec`:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
>>> getcontext().prec = 60
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I am trying to apply your answer, but I'm having a little issue. I get an error: `the_float = average*(high_output-low_output)+low_output
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'`
high_output is .5 low_output is 0 the average in this case was 0.179625286161899566650390625.
How can I do this math without error? Thanks!

Comment: @AndersonP Both operands need to be decimals, try `average*Decimal(high_output-low_output)+Decimal(low_output)`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `float` datatype in python can show upto 16 digits precision.

For higher precision (to retain all digits) , use special packages like : [mpmath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpmath)
You can use it like:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 64       #64 decimal places
sqrt(5)/2 #64 digit, high precision
```